# Test for boolean contradiction in javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean-operations

I need a function to tell me if a string representing a boolean algebra expression is contradictory. For a simple example, `"A & !A"` should return...true, I guess, if the function is answering the question "is this a contradiction?", or it should return false if the question is "could this work?".

Obviously the above example is trivial but I need something that could handle any crazy thing like `"A & (B|C) & ((!C|D) | E)"`. So I am wondering if such a function or library is already out there somewhere.

The purpose for this is that the variables in the strings are tag names and eventually I would compare it against a javascript object to see if its tag property contains or doesn't contain the tags, but these expressions are built programmatically and need to be tested before they are used to make sure that it is actually possible for them to find matching objects, because it isn't self-contradictory.

I guess a brute force way I could do it is to eval() every combination of true and false for each variable and see if any of them return true, but is that the best way?

Comment: There is no function for this. Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I haven't tried because it seems difficult to figure out (I haven't studied boolean algebra) and it seems like a common enough problem that it must have already been done.

Comment: Well, that's what search engines are for. I found [this](https://github.com/abozhilov/dmath/blob/master/boolean-algebra.html) in a matter of seconds. I didn't look into it in detail but it looks like it may be what you need.

Comment: @Evilzebra, yeah, I found that too. And that is all I found and I have no idea what it does or how to use it. It looks like it operates on HTML, which is weird.

Comment: No, it just accepts two values to its functions. Like `bool.xor(a,b)` with `a` and `b` being equal to 0 or 1. So you would need to build a function which could read your strings that you gave as an example, and use the appropriate function for each pair of comparisons.